# Border обтекающий фигуру

Tags: css

Существует ли у border свойство обтекающее фигуру не зависимо от заданных ширины и высоты?
З.Ы. Фигура сделана с помощью clip-path

Comment: вы имеете ввиду вот это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31854185/how-to-add-border-in-my-clip-path-polygon-css-style

Comment: Спасибо, ваш пример не сработал, но я с ним поколдовал и заработало

Comment: главное проблема решена)